# How to save a random item returned from QuerySet. Django, Python

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am trying to save the returned item from QuerySet, so that later it will display all the saved items in the next template. But I do not know how to go about it?

1.) how to send the 'shot' to the database correctly??

**My models.py**

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class UserDecision(models.Model):
    decision = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    relation = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

**My views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import User
from .forms import UserDecisionForm

def random_views(request):
    shot = User.objects.all().order_by('?')[:1]

    #Begining form here
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserDecisionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            decision = form.save(commit=False)
            decision.relation = shot #<--- how to pass this element to the database automatically. According to the result returned from the QuerySet query.
            decision.save()
    else:
        form = UserDecisionForm()

    # other elements
    context = {'shot': shot, 'form':form }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

from .models import UserDecision

class UserDecisionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserDecision
        fields = ('decision',)
```

Comment: `shot` is an array, you possibly missed that. What are you trying to achieve by assigning to `pk`? Are you trying to make a copy of a random user and display it in the template?

Comment: pk - is a remnant of the attempts I tried to make, acting in accordance with the documentation. Yes, I am trying to copy a random user, so that I can display it. I know how to save data from the form and how to create it. But how to save the result from QuerySet like (all() or order_by('?')). Do I have to create a separate model?  if so how to pass the queryset result to the model? I'm learning django and I have not found an adequate example.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Are you asking how could you assign something to `decision.relation`? If it's that take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Short version: try `decision.relation = [shot]`

Long version:
`decision.relation` will return a [related manager instance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/relations/); a manager much like the one that `<model>.objects` returns except that it manages all the records that are related to instance `decision`.
The caveat is that `decision.relation` is actually [a data descriptor](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html), a special attribute of an object (here: `decision`) that allows some neat little tricks upon accessing (`__get__`) or changing (`__set__`) the attribute:
Upon accessing the attribute `relation`, you are provided with the aforementioned manager instance through the descriptor's `__get__` method.

When setting the attribute (which you do with `decision.relation = some_variable`) the descriptor uses its `__set__` method which looks like this:

```
# django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.py: 518
def __set__(self, instance, value):
    """
    Set the related objects through the reverse relation.

    With the example above, when setting ``parent.children = children``:

    - ``self`` is the descriptor managing the ``children`` attribute
    - ``instance`` is the ``parent`` instance
    - ``value`` is the ``children`` sequence on the right of the equal sign
    """
    ...
    manager = self.__get__(instance)
    manager.set(value)
```

So when you write `decision.relation = shot`, thereby calling the above `__set__` method, the descriptor will create the right manager for that relation and then call [`set(shot)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.set) on it.
Finally, `set()` is expecting an *iterable* of model instances, but you only gave it a single model instance by itself.

---

I'm not quite sure if this will actually answer your question, but I didnt want to add long comment to the opening post and answers are more lucid when it comes to explaining code.

`values()` will return a queryset of dictionaries representations of the objects in a query. You can use these dictionaries to make identical copies of those objects.

```
user_data = User.objects.order_by('?').values()[:1][0]
user_data[User._meta.pk.name] = None # We cannot use an existing pk for the copy
copied_user = User.objects.create(**user_data)
return render(request, 'index.html', {'shot':copied_user})
```

It is not clear what you are doing with those copies on the next view. If you only want to display a copied object to avoid anyone actually making changes to the original and are then discarding the copies again once you leave the view (so as to not end up with a table full of copies), it would be better to change the template/use a simple form to only display the data of the original in the first place.

Comment: thank you for the answer, I mean the correct transfer of the shot to the database. I have clarified my query above.